# OS evaluate in bash script

Tags: bash, command-line

i was thinking in way that before run my script , evaluate which operating system that
user use ubuntu or solaris , am using this because there is some differences  
  in command option  in each OS such as `sed ..` , i was trying the following :

```
sysEval=`grep "ubuntu" | uname -a`

if [ sysEval ]; then

.......some command 

else ....... some command
fi
```

**NOTE That my script will run only in ubuntu or solaris** 
seems not working !

Comment: This question makes sense and has multiple upvoted answers. But it appears it may soon be closed. It would be good if at least one person who has voted to close this would explain *why* this should be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of parsing `uname -a` a better idea would be parsing output of `cat  /etc/*release*`.

Answer (score 4):

I'd probably do something like this:

```
os=$(uname -s)
case $os in
  Linux) 
    distro=$(lsb_release -si)
    case $distro in
      Ubuntu) 
        echo "Ubuntu, great!"
        ;;
      *) 
        echo "Sorry, Linux distribution '$distro' is not supported"
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac
    ;;
  SunOS) 
    echo "SunOS, great!"
    ;;
  *) 
    echo "Sorry, OS '$os' is not supported"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: nice and clean code as usual ....

Answer (score 3):

There is an environment variable:

```
echo $OSTYPE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 sysEval=cat /etc/*release* | awk 'FNR == 1 {print $1 }' | cut -d\= -f2
```

Comment: which sysEval will equal = ubuntu , if not .....Solaris

Comment: sysEval="$(cat .......... -f2)"